# apache error - 403 forbidden on virtual host via nginx reverse proxy

Tags: linux, apache, nginx

i'm using CentOS release 6.5 (Final) and i installed nginx-1.6.1-1.el6.ngx.x86_64, httpd-2.2.15-31.el6.centos.x86_64 using yum

packets flow like below

external -> nginx:80 -> apache:8080

when i access server via http://test.zfanta.com always meet 403 error

error log

```
[Thu Aug 21 03:34:06 2014] [error] [client 211.49.54.233] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

nginx setting

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  test.zfanta.com;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO http;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

apache setting

```
Listen 8080

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/*/www">
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/zfanta/www
    ServerName test.zfanta.com
    ErrorLog logs/test.zfanta.com-error
    CustomLog logs/test.zfanta.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and /home directory

/home/:
lost+found  test  zfanta

/home/lost+found:

/home/test:
www

/home/test/www:
index.html

/home/zfanta:
www

/home/zfanta/www:
index.php

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this

```
Directory "/home/*/www"
```

would work (probably it would apply **literally** to directory `/home/*/www`, but won't expand). Since `/` is forbidden by the first `Directory`, you get that 403. Use something like this instead:

```
Directory ~ "/home/[^/]+/www"
```

Comment: even i add
<Directory "/home/zfanta/www">
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride FIleInfo
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
it doesn't work

Comment: Does logs/test.zfanta.com-error say anything? Do you have any other VirtualHost?

Comment: logs/test.zfanta.com-error says nothing but (13)Permission denied. i don't have any other virtual host

Comment: If it does not say something like "permission denied by configuration", it could mean the apache process does not have read access to the file/folder. Check for at least r-x permissions for the apache user and/or group on the /home/zfanta/www and all its parents. Also, on CentOS, check if SELinux is enabled: check `sestatus` output and if enabled, check /var/log/audit/audit.log to see if it is preventing apache from accessing the files.